# wp_enqueue_script() without src in WooCommerce source code

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I was looking at the WooCommerce source code. I found `wp_enqueue_script()` without `src` parameter. What are these `wp_enqueue_script()` without `src` parameter are doing.

Filename: includes/admin/views/html-admin-page-product-export.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Admin View: Product Export
 *
 * @package WooCommerce/Admin/Export
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-product-export' );

$exporter = new WC_Product_CSV_Exporter();
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/**
 * Enqueue scripts.
 */
public function admin_scripts() {
    $suffix = defined( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG' ) && SCRIPT_DEBUG ? '' : '.min';
    wp_register_script( 'wc-product-export', WC()->plugin_url() . '/assets/js/admin/wc-product-export' . $suffix . '.js', array( 'jquery' ), WC_VERSION );
    wp_localize_script(
        'wc-product-export',
        'wc_product_export_params',
        array(
            'export_nonce' => wp_create_nonce( 'wc-product-export' ),
        )
    );
}
```

That script is already registered, so just need to enqueue - `woocommerce/includes/admin/class-wc-admin-exporters.php` #Line 88